# When insert some records in database-1->table-1 then same records should be insert in database-2->table-2 how to do this?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have a requirement that when we insert records in table1 of databse1 then same records should be inserted in table2 of database 2 is there any way to do this?
I have one way that will be while writing the insert query for table1 of database1 then I will write same insert query for table2 of database2 in this way I can do this but I want to know if there is any other way?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a procedure that executes both insert statements similar to the one below

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `doubleInsert` (`val-a` VARCHAR(255), `val-b` VARCHAR(255), ...)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO database-1.table-1 (col-a, col-b, ...)
    VALUES (val-a, val-b, ...);
    INSERT INTO database-2.table-2 (col-a, col-b, ...)
    VALUES (val-a, val-b, ...);
END$$
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What kind of "procedure" are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to do this, such as using logical replication, using a trigger which connects to the other system, handling this with some type of connection proxy, or a stored procedure which handles both inserts. To give a more specific answer though you'd really need to specify which database (and version) you are working with... mysql answers will be quite different than postgres answers.

Comment: Yes need in MySQL